# UIWebView sharing between views / persist state

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I understand this question was asked several times on stackoverflow, but still - is there any way I can persist or serialize UIWebView after it has fully loaded HTML, so I could instantly show it on another web view?

There must be some way, because iBooks does it - if you load a book for the first time it takes some time to load, but after that it loads instantly, even if you exit iBooks and load it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the HTML and and then pull it up quickly if you have it loaded based on date.

Try

```
    NSString *webHTML = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

then save it NSUserDefaults and with a NSDate object in a dictionary so you can see if you should reload it or if it was loaded 30 seconds ago.

Comment: Nope, this is still slow. What I want is to persist "rendered state" of a UIWebView, so I would not need to render html/css again, I think iBooks does that somehow.

Comment: possibly have it loaded using a singleton then and just load it on the other page might work.